# How to deploy asp.net core web app hosted by Kestrel that should support https with self-signed certificate

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, self-signed-certificate

I am deploying an asp.net core 3.1 web app. The tech stack is: Runs as docker container in a linux machine; Hosted by asp.net core out of box Kestrel server; Uses a self-signed certificate in testing environment. As a developer, I have very little knowledge on the technology involved in deployment. So please forgive me if I am not describing the needs clearly or even wrong, and I will appreciate any help very much.

We are usig docker-compose.yml to do the deployment. It works without the part to support https. The following is the related portion in the docker-compose.yml:

```
  WebApp:
    container_name: webapp
    image: deploying-version
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - WebRootPath=/app
    volumes:
      - /home/data:/app/data
      - /home/Config/webapp/appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json
```

I have setup https support on my development machine by export the visual studio generated self signed certificate and adding following part to the appsettingss.json and it seems supporting https:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:443",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "C:\\Temp\\localhost.pfx",
          "Password": "password"
        }
      }
    }
```

This  is the build image we use: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim

I am in a totally lost how to achieve what I need to. Can someone telles me the steps I should follow? Like how to generate the self-signed certificate in the linux box, how to setup the configurations or in the code to use the self-signed certificate to make https work?

I have used following commands to generate the self-signed certificate (https://andrewlock.net/creating-and-trusting-a-self-signed-certificate-on-linux-for-use-in-kestrel-and-asp-net-core/):

openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt
openssl req -config localhost.conf -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -days 3650 -out localhost.crt

And then added one line to the docker-compose to copy the localhost.pfx file into the container
- /home/Config/certs/localhost.pxf:/app/localhost.pfx
and changed the section related to Kestrel in appsettings.json

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://+:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://+:443",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "app/localhost.pfx",
          "Password": "password"
        }
      }
    }
```

However, when I am deploying the web app by running the docker-compose.yml, the web app can't be started. It has the following error:

Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_read_bio:not enough data
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromBio(SafeBioHandle bio, SafePasswordHandle password)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.ValidateOptions()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)